# Ajax GET request blocked by CORS policy while accessing files in localhost

Tags: node.js, ajax, server, cors

I am building a website which takes a query with several fields from the user and sends an ajax request to the node.js server to return the query search results. The server is running on localhost. But when I submit the query and send get request through ajax, it is blocked by the  CORS policy. I searched around about this and found out about servers blocking other domains accessing the server, but if I am accessing these files from the computer server is running does it still count as different domains. Also, I tried setting the request header in the server code usng the following code but it still doesn't work.

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, 
};
});
```

I can't use express for the project, so I am using pure node.js.

Here is my ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "localhost:8080",
    data: { action: 'search_tutors', homeTown: $('#homeTown').val() },
    cache: false,
    success: function (results) {
        showResults(results);
    },
    error: function (request, err) {

        alert(err);
        console.log(err);
    },
    done: function () {
        alert("Done");
        console.log("Done");
    }
});
```

What should I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'` and `'Access-Control-Request-Method', '*'` to the headers

```
var server;
server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    // Set CORS headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, POST, GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if ( req.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
        return;
    }

// other codes
});
```